# Simple PHP, jQuery email form

Tags: jquery, forms, email

Have a problem with my Mail form, the HTML seems fine, the jQuery part too and PHP is all correct as well. The part i'm having an issue with is that the jQuery can't catch the error response from the PHP script.
It should load the data from the response and put it in a class, but nothing happens, yet i can see the response in the console.

here's the jquery :

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "send_email.php",
        data:'name='+emailData.name+'&email='+
        emailData.email+'&subject='+
        'Hello'+'&body='+
        emailData.body,
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
            $("#contactForm .status").html(data);
        },
        error:function(data){
          $('#modal .modal-body').html(data);      
        }
    });
```

and the PHP script :

```
$toEmail = "admin@phppot_samples.com"; 
$mailHeaders = "From: " . $_POST["name"] . "<". $_POST["email"] .">\r\n";
if(mail($toEmail,  $_POST["subject"], $_POST["body"], $mailHeaders)) {
    print "<p class='success'>Mail Sent.</p>";
} else {
    print "<p class='error'>Problem in Sending Mail.</p>";
}
```

So, any ideas why i can't catch the error response ?
p.s. i only included the necessary bits of the code.

Comment: `error` is fired if there is actual HTTP error. I.e. server error 500 or 404 or something. You are, however, returning data if PHP `mail()` happens to fail. `ajax` treats it as a successful call.

Comment: In addition to the other's error comments, I'd say you're violating some kind of spam filter. `$_POST['email']` would have to be from the same domain sending the mail. Otherwise you should be passing `$_POST['email']` as the Reply-To header. So you can get a false positive on `mail()` but the server still fails to send, or the mail never comes because the client rejected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both responses will be captured in the `success` handler. The `error` handler is for when the HTTP response code is not `200` etc (like `4xx`, `5xx`). If you want to trigger the error handler, use

```
} else { 
   header('500 Problem' );
   print "<p class='error'>...</p>";
}
```

That said, if you can gracefully detect the error, you should check for the status in your `success` handler by examining the response data.

Comment: This is it. :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

PHP's mail function is odd,

from the [main page for mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

> Returns TRUE if the mail was
>   successfully accepted for delivery,
>   FALSE otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just
>   because the mail was accepted for
>   delivery, it does **NOT** mean the mail
>   will actually reach the intended
>   destination.

---

Basically there is nothing you *really* can do in plain ol' PHP unless you ***actually*** check the wire to see what is going on. I would suggest using some mail library that has some indication of whether the mail sent or not (if it exists)

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to occur a real problem server side in order to be interpreted as an error. When the email method fails sending the email, it will return false, but the request is working fine anyway, so it will always return at your success method. An Internal server error must occur to make the code return to the error method. You may throw an exception or something like that (I don´t know if php can do it) in order to make the code to return at the error method.

A different approach could be returning a status code. Let's say

```
Status 0-> Email sent
Status 1-> Email not sent
```

And check that status in your success method and choose what text to display to the user